# I'm having trouble understand what this javascript code snippet means. Can someone give comments line by line?

Tags: javascript, io-socket

I know that it's supposed to take the text and send it to each socket but I'm not sure as to what each line does.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
  return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Maybe start overhere: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  // create a new socket which connects to `/` by default
  var socket = io()
  // add a submission handler to any form on the current page
  $("form").submit(function() {
    // emit the value stored in the element identified by the id `m` as an argument for the `chat message` event in socket io
    socket.emit("chat message", $("#m").val())
    // clear the value stored in `#m`
    $("#m").val("")
    // prevent event propagation
    return false
  })
})
```

I'd say this code is a little incorrect since it would trigger on any form submission - if you had multiple forms you would end up in trouble :)

Comment: How would I be able to specify which form? Can you give an example?

Comment: You could mark the form with an id attribute, like is done with `m` in this example, and then replace `'form'` with `'#yourid'`. For example if you changed the form being submitted to have the id attribute 'chat' - like `<form id='chat'>` then you would use `$('#chat')` instead of `$('#form')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
// When the document is ready
// jQuery shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {

  // create a new socket and assign it to the socket variable
  var socket = io();

  // when the form is submitted
  $('form').submit(function() {
  
    // emit a "chat message" event containing the value
    // of of the element with the `m` id
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    
    // set that element's value to empty string 
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
});
```